# How to add apache server config rewrite rule for encoding pipe symbol in url

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am getting a 404 error on URL that contains pipe symbol. If I encode manually with `%7C` for pipe it works properly. I want to add a rule in Apache conf file that automatically replaces pipe character anywhere in the URL with `%7C`.

Ex: (Not working)

```
www.example.com/search/?term=test&another=1|2|3
```

This above URL works if changed as below,

```
www.example.com/search/?term=test&another=1%7C2%7C3
```

(URL needs in this format)

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: May you can find useful idea [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22114892/13944750)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a rule in Apache conf file that automatically replaces pipe character anywhere in the URL with %7C.

You have to do the replacement *client side*. You *can't* do it server side. It's too late at that stage - you have to do it before the client *sends* the request. `|` is not a [valid character](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).